# If type is "10" then don't display customer Name "a"

Tags: sql

I have this data:

```
Customer Name    Type    Domain  start date  end date    ID Number
    a            10       TV     2/26/2019   5/1/2022    q001
    a            11       TV     2/26/2019   5/1/2022    q002
    a            12       TV     2/26/2019   5/1/2022    q003
    b            11       TV     2/26/2019   5/1/2022    q004
    c            10       TV     2/26/2019   5/1/2022    q005
    c            11       TV     2/26/2019   5/1/2022    q006
    c            12       TV     2/26/2019   5/1/2022    q007
    d            12       TV     2/26/2019   5/1/2022    q008
```

I need a query to exclude all records for any customer having a `Type` value of `10`. So the 2nd and 3rd records for customer `a` should be excluded, even though their types are `11` and `12`, because there is also a type `10` record available for that customer.

Here is what the result set should look like based on the sample data above:

```
Customer Name    Type    Domain  start date  end date    ID Number
    b            11       TV     2/26/2019   5/1/2022    q004
    d            12       TV     2/26/2019   5/1/2022    q008
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Hint: You are looking for customers for which *not exists* a type-10 record.

Comment: SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE Not (Type = 10) this won't work as I don't want a   11  TV  2/26/2019   5/1/2022    q002
a   12  TV  2/26/2019   5/1/2022    q003 as well, as same customer name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `NOT IN` subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable a
WHERE [Customer Name] NOT IN (
    SELECT [Customer Name] FROM MyTable b
    WHERE Type = 10
)
```

Comment: I don't how to use your query in this nested query, I am using with x and join              with x as ( ) table in this query. I have table as below       
"with x as ( select cust.customer_Name, cust.group, id.type,org.domain, id.start, id.end from customer cust,identification id,
id ......

where.....)) select customer_Name, Type, Domain, Start_Date, End_date, ID_number
where domain='TV' "

Comment: Well without complete info you're not going to get a complete answer. Do you just need to use `x` instead of `MyTable` above?

Answer (score 1):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where customername = t.customername and type = 10 
)
```